# Insertar imagen en cuerpo de Correo mediante C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, smtp

Envío un correo mediante C#, pero deseo anexar imagenes al cuerpo del Correo.
Tengo el siguiente método:

```
   private bool sendEmail(string filename, Task<IEnumerable<dataTokenReport>> val, string to, string emailLogin, string initDate, string endDate)
    {
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 1 email" + filename, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        Boolean response = false;
        Attachment data = new Attachment(filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Resultado de data" + data, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        try
        {
            if (filename != null && filename != string.Empty)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 2 name email" + name, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                var asunto = name.Split('.');
                String textoEmail = "";
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); ;
                // utilizamos el servidor SMTP de gmail
                client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Port);
                client.Host = Ip;
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.Timeout = 1000000000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // nos autenticamos con nuestra cuenta de gmail
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

                mail.From = new MailAddress(From);
                mail.Subject = asunto[0];
                var test = val.Result;
                //mail.Body ="Equipo G500" + Environment.NewLine + " El archivo no pudo ser procesado ya que no tiene el formato correcto de blacklist para cuentas PREMIER bloqueadas hasta el día " + dateFormat + " . " + Environment.NewLine + "Saludos";
                textoEmail = Environment.NewLine +  "assets/img/pc1.png";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "                                                                     Día y fecha de solicitud";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "                                                                     " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "." + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "Estimado Usuario," + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "Adjunto a este correo se encuentra el archivo\n\r";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "con el reporte solicitado con período de\n\r";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + ("consulta del [" + initDate + "]-[" + endDate + "]").Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "Usuario que solicita: " + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + emailLogin + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "assets/img/mailexcelfoot.png";                                
                mail.Body = textoEmail;
                mail.Attachments.Add(data);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Antes de mandarlo" + mail.Body, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                client.Send(mail);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "ya lo mando", "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                response = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLogError(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoOut, ex.Message, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Tengo las imagenes **pc1** y **mailexcelfoot** en las carpetas **assets** el problema es que me lo pinta como texto, agradeceré Ayuda, cabe mencionar que todo el proceso lo hace de manera correcta...

--EDICION--

Estoy usando vistas alternativas pero aún así no he logrado conseguirlo anexo metodo modificado.

```
    private bool sendEmail(string filename, Task<IEnumerable<dataTokenReport>> val, string to, string emailLogin, string initDate, string endDate)
    {
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 1 email" + filename, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        Boolean response = false;
        Attachment data = new Attachment(filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Resultado de data" + data, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        try
        {
            if (filename != null && filename != string.Empty)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 2 name email" + name, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                var asunto = name.Split('.');
                String textoEmail = "";
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); ;
                // utilizamos el servidor SMTP de gmail
                client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Port);
                client.Host = Ip;
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.Timeout = 1000000000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // nos autenticamos con nuestra cuenta de gmail
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                mail.From = new MailAddress(From);
                mail.Subject = asunto[0];
                var test = val.Result;
                //mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                //mail.Body ="Equipo G500" + Environment.NewLine + " El archivo no pudo ser procesado ya que no tiene el formato correcto de blacklist para cuentas PREMIER bloqueadas hasta el día " + dateFormat + " . " + Environment.NewLine + "Saludos";
                textoEmail = Environment.NewLine + "assets/img/pc1.png" + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "                                                                     Día y fecha de solicitud";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "                                                                     " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "." + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "Estimado Usuario," + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine +  "Adjunto a este correo se encuentra el archivo";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "con el reporte solicitado con período de";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + ("consulta del [" + initDate + "]-[" + endDate + "]").Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "Usuario que solicita: " + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + emailLogin + Environment.NewLine;
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "assets/img/mailexcelfoot.png";
                textoEmail = textoEmail + Environment.NewLine + "assets/img/mailexcelfoot.png";
                //string textBody = textoEmail;
                //AlternateView plainTextView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textBody, null, "text/html");

                //string htmlBody = "<html><body>" + textBody + "<img src = cid:facebook />" + "</body></html>";
                //AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

                //string imagePathF = @"D:\PROYECTOS NET\Affiliate Monitor\PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor.Website\dev_Angular\src\assets\img\pc1.png";//aqui la ruta de tu imagen
                //LinkedResource face = new LinkedResource(imagePathF);
                //face.ContentId = "facebook";
                //htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(face);
                //mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                AlternateView VISTAHTML = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textoEmail, null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

                    // DEFINE DE DONDE SE OBTIENEN LAS IMAGENES
                    LinkedResource IMAGEN1 = new LinkedResource(@"D:\PROYECTOS NET\Affiliate Monitor\PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor.Website\assets\img\pc1.png", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                    IMAGEN1.ContentId = "IMG1";
                    VISTAHTML.LinkedResources.Add(IMAGEN1); // LA AÑADE AL MENSAJE HTML
                    LinkedResource IMAGEN2 = new LinkedResource(@"D:\PROYECTOS NET\Affiliate Monitor\PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor.Website\assets\img\mailexcelfoot.png", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                    IMAGEN2.ContentId = "IMG2";
                    VISTAHTML.LinkedResources.Add(IMAGEN2); // LA AÑADE AL MENSAJE HTML

                    MailMessage MENSAJE = new MailMessage(); // DECLARA EL MENSAJE....
                    mail.AlternateViews.Add(VISTAHTML); // ... Y QUE VA EN FORMATO HTML

                //mail.Body = VISTAHTML;
                mail.Attachments.Add(data);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Antes de mandarlo" + mail.Body, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                client.Send(mail);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "ya lo mando", "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                response = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLogError(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoOut, ex.Message, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 3):

la forma que yo uso es la siguiente:
1. El cuerpo del mensaje tienes que enviarlo como html
2. Tienes que incrustar las imágenes en el mensaje

Añade a tu función estas lineas antes de la linea mail.Body=textoEmail

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

string textBody = textoEmail;
AlternateView plainTextView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

string htmlBody = "<html><body>"+textBody+"</body></html>";
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

string imagePathF = @"img/facebook.jpg";//aqui la ruta de tu imagen
LinkedResource face = new LinkedResource(imagePathF);
face.ContentId = "facebook";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(face);

msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Tu cuerpo del mensaje deberá tener un código HTML como este:

```
<IMG id="facebook border"="0" alt="facebook" src="cid:facebook" width="24" height="24">
```

De esta forma, incrusta la imagen dentro del mensaje y se deberia de ver.

Saludos.

Comment: Intento manejarlo como lo indicas, pero aún no consigo anexar la imagen

Comment: Mira este enlace: https://matypereira.wordpress.com/2008/12/14/enviar-mails-con-imagenes-en-c-net/

Answer (score 0):

Después de un poco de manejo, lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
  private bool sendEmail(string filename, Task<IEnumerable<dataTokenReport>> val, string to, string emailLogin, string initDate, string endDate)
    {
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 1 email" + filename, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        Boolean response = false;
        Attachment data = new Attachment(filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Resultado de data" + data, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        try
        {
            if (filename != null && filename != string.Empty)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Donde se aloja el reporta temporalmentes 2 name email" + name, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                var asunto = name.Split('.');
                String textoEmail = "";
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); ;
                // utilizamos el servidor SMTP de gmail
                client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Port);
                client.Host = Ip;
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.Timeout = 1000000000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                // nos autenticamos con nuestra cuenta de gmail
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                mail.From = new MailAddress(From);
                mail.Subject = asunto[0];
                var test = val.Result;

                //mail.Body ="Equipo G500" + Environment.NewLine + " El archivo no pudo ser procesado ya que no tiene el formato correcto de blacklist para cuentas PREMIER bloqueadas hasta el día " + dateFormat + " . " + Environment.NewLine + "Saludos";


                textoEmail = "               " + "<br><b>Día y fecha de solicitud</b>"
                + "               " + "<br>" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "." 
                + "<br><br>Estimado Usuario,<br><br>"
                + "Adjunto a este correo se encuentra el archivo<br>"
                + "con el reporte solicitado con período de <br>"
                + ("consulta del <b>[" + initDate + "]-[" + endDate + "]</b>").Trim()
                + "<br><br>Usuario que solicita: <br><br>"
                + emailLogin + "<br><br>";



                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(" <img src=cid:companylogo>" + textoEmail + " <img src=cid:excel><br>" + asunto[0] + "<br><br> <img src=cid:mailfoot>", null, "text/html");
                mail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                var aa = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(aa +  @"assets\img\pc1.png");
                System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource2 = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(aa + @"assets\img\images.png");
                System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource3 = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(aa + @"assets\img\mailfoot.png");


                //System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource1 = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/assets/img/pc1.png");


                imageResource.ContentId = "companylogo";
                imageResource2.ContentId = "excel";
                imageResource3.ContentId = "mailfoot";
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource2);
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource3);
                mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                mail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                mail.Attachments.Add(data);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "Antes de mandarlo" + mail.Body, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                client.Send(mail);
                _log.WriteLogInfo(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoIn, "ya lo mando", "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                response = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLogError(TypeMessageFormat.TEXT, LoggingQueue.InfoOut, ex.Message, "PC.MX.Affiliate.Monitor", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Como puede observarse incluso logro agregar 3 imágenes en diferente posiciones, creo que el trabajo lo realiza el **AlternateView** jugando con el "text/html" y el **LinkedResources**.